# Difference between string str and string str=null

Tags: c#

I want to know what exactly happens inside when we declare a variable, like this:

```
string tr;

string tr = null;
```

While debugging, I noticed for both values that it was showing null only. But when using `ref tr` without initializing `null` it will give error while the second line doesn't.

Please help me to know about it in depth

Comment: You need an **Explicit** initialisation to use variable as an `ref` parameter, even `null` assignmenet is fine.that's not happening in your first variable declaration.

Comment: It is just to make sure, you did not forget to assign a value to the variable -> if you would forget it, you could run into problems

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> While debugging, I noticed for both values that it was showing null
>   only

That's right because `string` is a [*reference type*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx) and the default value for all reference types is `null`.

But C# compiler doesn't allow the use of *uninitialized* variables.

Your first example is just a variable declaration. But your second one is variable initialization.

That's why if you write;

```
string tr;
Console.WriteLine(tr);
```

you get compiler error like;

> Use of unassigned local variable 'tr'

From [`ref (C# Reference)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx)

> An argument that is passed to a ref parameter **must be initialized
>   before it is passed**.

Although variables passed as [`out` arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx) don't have to be initialized before being passed.

Answer (score 9):

Your first statement is just declaration and your second statement is Declaration + Initialization.

```
string tr; // Just Declaration

string tr=null; //Declaration + Initialization.
```

You may get compile time errors if you try to use `tr` with just declaration. *(first case*) for example:

```
string tr; // Just Declaration
if (tr == "")   //Use of unassigned local variable
{
}
```

Same error will be generated for `ref` keyword, which requires the field to be explicitly assigned something *(Declaration + Initialization)*. With `out` keyword though, you can use just declaration, but the method would be responsible for making sure that some value is assigned to the `out` parameter.

Comment: but this error wont be there in case of int ,long.That is we can use a variable declaring like int i; without initializing ,where compiler will assign zero by default. but why not not in case of string.

Comment: @keerti_h, error would be same, try `int i; if (i == 0){}` or `int i;  Console.WriteLine(i);` , you would get the same error, also try it with a method with `ref` keyword. So the error will be there.

Comment: @keerti_h, although string is a reference type whereas the others you mentioned are value types, but that will not change the error.

Comment: ,i did try that with ref, but i declared that as global that's why it assigned Zero probably. i will try with local also

Comment: @keerti_h, that is a different thing, By global I guess you meant at class level, in that case it is a field not a local method variable and fields are assigned default value at the time of object instantiation *(if they are just declared and not initialized with any value)*.

Comment: yes i agree habib .i meant to say that  i tried using int i;with ref . but it worked fine.let me try once again.thank you

Answer (score 4):

The compliler requires you to explicitly set the `null` (or any other) value to the variable. It wants no misuderstandings and less runtime errors in your program so it gently infers that you might not initialized a variable before using it.

The exception is using a method with `out` parameter (which itself guarantees initialization) as uninitialized variable.

Comment: While it is Visual Studio that reports the errors to the users, it's the compiler's requirements and not VS'.